# Find the middle number in the $29$th row in the Pascal's Triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients, contest-math

This question is taken from the Singapore Mathematical Olmpiad training notes for Primary school.

Find the middle number in the $29$th row of the [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

For example, the middle number in $3$rd row is $2$, $5$th row is $6$, $7$th row is $20$, etc.

What technique can a primary student used to answer this question?

Comment: Primary students are not supposed to use combinatorics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a slightly odd question.  Although it's for primary school, it is also Olympiad training, so I would say it's reasonable to expect that students will know that the number is
$$\binom{28}{14}=\frac{28\times27\times\cdots\times15}{14\times13\times\cdots\times1}\ .$$
If you now cancel lots of common factors it reduces to
$$27\times25\times23\times2\times2\times19\times17\times8
  =27\times23\times19\times17\times8\times100$$
and assuming calculators are allowed, this is not too bad.

Comment: Primary kids who go to olympiads in most countries that do well in the IMO know this by about third grade.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't any idea what means are available to the students for making the calculation, but I'm wondering whether they are supposed to notice that in the sequence of numbers for $ \ _{2n}C_{n} \ = \ \binom{2n}{n} \ , $

$$ 1 \ \ 2 \ \ 6 \ \ 20 \ \ 70 \ \ 252 \ \ 924 \ \ 3432 \ \ \ldots \ \ , $$

each entry is $ \ 3 \ + \ \frac{n-2}{n} \ \ = \ \ \frac{4n-2}{n} \ $ times the preceding one, or

$$ \binom{2n}{n} \ \ = \ \frac{4n-2}{n} \ \cdot \ \binom{2n-2}{n-1} \ \ . $$  One would *still* have to multiply fourteen times to get to the 29th row, but this seems a little less awful than looking for all the canceling prime factors in a direct calculation from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $1^{st}$ row are the binomial coefficients of $(a+b)^0$, the $29^{th}$ row are the coefficients of $(a+b)^{28}.$

Here is a fairly easy rule to generate that row.

$1, 28, \frac{28*27}{2}, \frac{28*27}{2}\frac{26}{3}$.... each entry is the entry before it, times one number less, divided by one number greater.

The middle number will be the last number before what you multiply by is less than what you are dividing by.

It it probably more work to calculate than what David suggests above, but might be easier to teach.